# Google Play services out of date in emulator and cannot be updated

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

I've bumped my project to Google Play Services v8.3.0. But when I start any app that depends on 8.3.0 on the latest API 23 emulator, the version check fails.

Pressing "update" does not work because of course there is no Play Store on the emulator.

For example: try one of these Google's sample projects https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/

Is this just a limitation of the emulator - does not yet have latest Google Play Services? Or is there something that can be done to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new emulator with the latest android version. This worked for me before.

Comment: Nope, that does not help. I suspect we just have to wait for Google to update their emulator.